# R markdown flexdashboard dygraph height and width

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, dygraphs, flexdashboard

[Please see this pic at first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPWVC.png)

I have a question about my dygraph height and width. I successfully run my flexdashboard but the graph is cut. How can I let my graph to form properly.
Following is my fledashboard code.

```
checkboxGroupInput("type", "Choose company", 
                       choices = names(stat_xts)[-1])
renderDygraph({
    req(input$type)     
        stat_xts1 <- stat_xts[, c("year", input$type)]
           dygraph(stat_xts1, main = "EP statistics",xlab = "time") %>%
      dyHighlight(highlightCircleSize = 4,hideOnMouseOut = T,
                  highlightSeriesBackgroundAlpha = 0.5,
                  highlightSeriesOpts = list(strokeWidth = 4)) %>%
      dyOptions(drawPoints = TRUE, pointSize = 2, fillGraph = TRUE, fillAlpha = 0.2, maxNumberWidth = 12, colors = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(7, "Dark2")) %>%
      dyRangeSelector(height = 30, strokeColor = "teel") %>%
      dyLegend(show = "onmouseover", width = 500)
  })
```

Thanks a lot. StackOverflow is awesome.

Comment: `dygraphOutput` in your UI has arguments for width and height.

Comment: @Axeman oh. thanks for ur hint. I check the help about dygraphOutput, but there are two usage: dygraphOutput and renderDygraph. How to distinguish them. If I want to change the width and height, do I add dygraphOutput directly in my code showed above? very appreciate!

Comment: in your ui.R you can adjust you size using dygraphOutput("dygraph", height=100, width=50)